# How to remove apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png error

Tags: drupal-6, apple-touch-icon

I am getting this warning into drupal6 recent log

(page not found Aug 29  apple-touch-icon.png    Anonymous (not verified))
(page not found Aug 29  apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png    Anonymous (not verified))..

How to remove this apple-touch-icon.png or apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png?

Comment: You should be able to remove the error by specifying where to find the icon, adding some html to you page.
See the full details here: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons

I guess the question that still remains is how do you tell the iOS device that you do not have, and are not going to create, and icon for them. Link to some nonexisting resource elsewhere on the net?

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the icon: the issue is that the icon is already missing. When a user with an iOS device (iPhone/iPad) bookmarks your site, or adds it to the home screen, the mobile browser makes a request for this file. Drupal is merely reporting this as a 404, missing file.